# Stop a form from being submitted unless specified amount of checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, submit

I am creating a page that allows users access to a certain section of my website if they click 8 out of 25 checkboxes in the right sequence.

First of all thanks to Reigel for the orignal code, he took what I had and rewrote it, its way better than what I initialy started with. Also thanks to Peter Ajtai for helping me optimize the code.

My question is, how can I disable the submit, or stop the form from being submitted unless at least 8 checkboxes have been checked, as well as account for someone unchecking the eighth checkbox which would again disable the form from being submitted.

Here is a live Version: [Click Here to see a live working version](http://jsfiddle.net/xSsrC/2/)

My code is as follows:

```
<body onLoad="clearForms()" onUnload="clearForms()">

 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="check_combination.php">
<table width="200" border="1" align="center">

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="5"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="6"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="7"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="8"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="9"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="10"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="11"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="12"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="13"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="14"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="15"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="16"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="17"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="18"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="19"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="20"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="21"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="22"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="23"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="24"/></td>
 <td width="20" align="center" valign="middle"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="25"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="23" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle" class="label"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="28" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" value="Test length" id="test" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="28" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td height="28" colspan="5" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="button" name="button" id="button2" value="Test hidden input value" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

<input name="result" type="hidden" id="result" />

</form>

</body>
```

And the javascript:

```
function clearForms() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
       document.forms[i].reset();
    $(':checkbox[name=checkbox]:disabled').attr('disabled', false);

    }
}


//initial checkCount of zero
var checkCount = 0;

//maximum number of allowed checked boxes
var maxChecks = 8;

$(document).ready(function() {

clearForms();

var $nameCheckbox = $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox]');

    $nameCheckbox.click(function() {

        //update checkCount
        checkCount = $('input:checked').length;

        if (checkCount >= maxChecks) {
            //alert('you may only choose up to ' + maxChecks + ' options');
            $nameCheckbox.not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $nameCheckbox.filter(':disabled').attr('disabled', false);
        }

        if (this.checked) {
            $("td.label").append('<label>' + this.value + ' </label>');
        } else {
            $("td.label").find(':contains(' + this.value + ')').remove();
        }

        $('input[name="result"]').val($("td.label").text());

    });


    $("#test").click(function() {
        alert($('input:checked').length)
    });

    $('#button2').click(function() {
        alert($('input[name="result"]').val());
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$(document).ready()` handler add a [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event handler for the `<form>`, like this:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
  if($("input:checkbox:checked").length < 8) {
    alert("You must select at least 8 things!");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

The [`event.preventDeault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) call prevents the form from submitting if the count of checkboxes checked is under 8, since it's checked at the time of submission, there's no enable/disable trickery here...we're just checking at the right time.